# Listing locales from /usr/share/i18n/locales

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to (alphabetically) list all locales found in `/usr/share/i18n/locales`, along with the corresponding `language` and `territory` text found in all the locale files. How can get the output to look like this?

```
en_US - American English, United States
en_GB - British English, United Kingdom
```

Listing all the locale names is easy:

```sh
ls /usr/share/i18n/locales/*
```

But for the additional information, I tried an `awk` command, but it is nowhere near what I need:

```sh
awk '/language   /||/territory  /{print $2}' /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like:

```
cd /usr/share/i18n/locales/ 
awk '/language   /{l=$2} /territory  /{print FILENAME " - "l ", " $2}' *
```

You can just "clear" `$1` and use `$0` that has leading space in it.

```
awk '$1 == "language"{$1="";l=$0} $1 == "territory"{$1="";print FILENAME " -" l "," $0}' *
```

Comment: @bojanmilevski You can upvote and/or accept the answers you like.

Answer (score 1):

Using `locale` command to list all available locales and then show requested details

```
#!/bin/bash

for l in $(locale -a); do
    read -r tmp1 lan tmp2 terr < <(LC_IDENTIFICATION="$l" locale -c language -c territory | tr '\n' ' ')
    echo "$l - $lan, $terr"
done
```

One-liner:

```
for l in $(locale -a); do read -r tmp1 lan tmp2 terr < <(LC_IDENTIFICATION="$l" locale -c language -c territory | tr '\n' ' '); echo "$l - $lan, $terr"; done
```

Another version:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
for l in $(locale -a); do
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="$l" locale -c 'language' -c 'territory' | \
    awk -v loc="$l" '{if(NR==2){ a=$0 }else if(NR==4){ print loc " - " a "," $0 }}'
done
```

Result:

```
aa_DJ - Afar,Djibouti
aa_DJ.utf8 - Afar,Djibouti
aa_ER - Afar,Eritrea
aa_ER@saaho - Afar,Eritrea
aa_ET - Afar,Ethiopia
af_ZA - Afrikaans,South Africa
af_ZA.utf8 - Afrikaans,South Africa
agr_PE - Aguaruna,Peru
ak_GH - Akan,Ghana
am_ET - Amharic,Ethiopia
....
```